# Get unique values from range of cells

Tags: google-sheets

Let's say I have a column of values (*e.g.*, first names). There may be some duplicate data (some first names are very common).

How can I get the *unique* values?

In SQL I would do

```
SELECT DISTINCT first_name FROM...
```

How can I do it in a Google Spreadsheet?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In Google Spreadsheets, you can use the `UNIQUE()` formula to do that.

### Formula

```
=UNIQUE(A1:A10)
```

### Explained

For the range as seen in the screenshot, there are 10 entries. The `UNIQUE()` formula accepts a range and filters out the duplicates and returns that range, see screenshot, leaving only 7 unique entries.

### Screenshot

[image]

### Reference

- [Google Spreadsheets Help: UNIQUE()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198?hl=en-GB)

Comment: How does `UNIQUE` work exactly? In your example you specified the formula only in cell `B1`, yet values appear in `B2`, `B3`, `B4`, etc.. so clearly the `UNIQUE` function has some "magic" behaviour in that it alters cells around it even though they don't contain a value or formula.

Comment: @Dai In the past, the cells in which the formula had expanded to (like B2, B3 ... etc), contained formula's as well: CONTINUE(). With the new Sheets this is no longer the case. If it can't expand, then it will through an error: #REF!

Comment: This answer is a little misleading in that it shows an ideal case where all unique names appear before a duplicate is seen.